# SQLite record update speed improvements

Tags: database, performance, sqlite

I currently have trouble updating SQLite database records at scale within a healthy amount of time.

I have a small database of about 70,000 records and I have some office personal using Navicat to filter the records and make some bulk edits to commit. When trying to perform an UPDATE on a large amount of records in one field everything comes to a crawl, when I look at the raw SQL query I can see that the program is using an UPDATE ..SET.. WHERE to perform the operations.

My question is what can I do to help this query run faster? I have a SQLite auto index on the column used for matching the record to update, but I have read and searched all over and have yet to see any kind of resolve other then what I already have in place. Updating one field in 20,000 records is literally taking close to 3 hours...regardless of using Navicat or not. The whole database is only 30mb so I have to be doing something wrong.

All other database operations run nice and speedy, not sure whats wrong and looking for some guidance from a SQLite vet.

Comment: Does that UPDATE use subqueries?

Comment: An example of what I can see from the raw output is: UPDATE table SET column=1.0 WHERE (column_value='value')

column_value is a SQLite auto indexed column if that matters...

Answer (score 0):

There are very few reasons why SQLite can perform as poorly as you describe, but I've experienced pretty much the same thing.

First, if you are performing a table-wide update on an indexed column, you're gonna thrash the whole index, all while making the index less useless. Delete the index before you update, then recreate the index.

Additionally, you can get some serious perf boost by changing the synchronous [PRAGMA](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html), but it comes with a non-zero amount of extra risk of corrupt data on a crash (extremely unlikely in my experience)

```
PRAGMA schema.synchronous = 0
```

Comment: Ill try editing the schema to see if it helps. As far as the index is concerned, I'm not updating the column that was indexed. I'm updating another field but have an sqlite_auto_index on the column that is being used to match records that need to be updated. None the less, could the schema setup be enough to make updating everything that slow?